# How do I convert a folder of images to a npy file?

Tags: python, image, numpy

I have a folder containing images of gestures. But to make it work on my code I need to change it to X.npy and Y.npy. I looked for many questions regarding this kinda problems but still in the dark. How do I evaluate this? How do I convert the folder to create npy dataset of my own? Is there any code for this or any converter?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I found a piece of code for this purpose on github.

```
from PIL import Image
import os, sys
import cv2
import numpy as np

'''
Converts all images in a directory to '.npy' format.
Use np.save and np.load to save and load the images.
Use it for training your neural networks in ML/DL projects. 
'''

# Path to image directory
path = "/path/to/image/directory/"
dirs = os.listdir( path )
dirs.sort()
x_train=[]

def load_dataset():
    # Append images to a list
    for item in dirs:
        if os.path.isfile(path+item):
            im = Image.open(path+item).convert("RGB")
            im = np.array(im)
            x_train.append(im)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    load_dataset()
    
    # Convert and save the list of images in '.npy' format
    imgset=np.array(x_train)
    np.save("imgds.npy",imgset)
```

Comment: Yeah I saw that too, but I'm note sure if I get anything after running this. I mean where do I find the folder where the images are converted

Comment: I just tried the same code on collab. It make a "imgds.npy" file in the root folder. Try the code on your own.

Comment: Still couldn't figure it out, but lemme try it again. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the code snippet in the following GitHub repo, that I found in google to convert a folder of images to a npy file:

https://gist.github.com/anilsathyan7/ffb35601483ac46bd72790fde55f5c04

Here in this case entire images in the folder are converted into NumPy array and are appended in a list named x_train.To convert and save this list of images in a single '.npy' format file, we can use the same code snippet:

```
    imgset=np.array(x_train)
    np.save("imgds.npy",imgset)
```

To convert and save this list of images in multiple '.npy' format files, use  below code snippet :

```
    imgset=np.array(x_train,dtype=object)
    for i in range(len(imgset)):
        np.save("imgds"+str(i)+".npy",imgset[i])
```